# While Restoring snapshot via Settings Only, Numbering Sequence gets Reset for which data exists

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

There is option to configure snapshot for reset values of some column.

How can I apply multiple conditions in ResetColumn Attribute?

I tried but not able to reproduce exact result .
Please help me
Thanks in advance
Regards

for e.g.
**

```
<ResetColumn name="LastNbr" value="[StartNbr]@NumberingID!=QCSP" />
```

---- "Working"
**
*

```
<ResetColumn name="LastNbr" value="[StartNbr]@NumberingID!=QCSP and @NumberingID!=QCPLAN" />
```

---- "Not Working"*

Comment: Hello @subodh, This is currently in progress to be fixed in the future releases.